# Removing Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to remove the value of a ForeignKey. Here are my models:

```
class WatchList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Thing(models.Model)
    watchlist = models.ForeignKey(WatchList, null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to remove a `Thing` from a user's `WatchList`. I have tried to do it this way, but this removes the entire `Thing`, not its place in the watchlist:

```
def delete(request, id):
    thing = get_object_or_404(Thing, pk=id)
    if thing.watchlist.user == request.user:
        thing.watchlist.delete() ## also tried thing.watchlist.user.delete() unsuccessfully
        return HttpResponseRedirect('somewhere')
    else:
        # other stuff
```

How do I remove a `Thing`from a user's `WatchList` without deleting the whole thing?

---

EDIT (realizing that I should use a `ManyToMany` relationship. Thanks to the commentors!)

```
class Thing(models.Model)
    watchlist = models.ManyToManyField(WatchList)
```

---

EDIT (trying to delete ManyToMany):

```
thing = get_object_or_404(Thing, pk=id)
wl = WatchList.objects.get(user=request.user)
if wl.user == request.user:
    thing.watchlist.remove(wl)
```

Comment: Should `Thing` remain in the database, or be deleted entirely?

Comment: Also, unless a given `Thing` can only ever be in 1 user's watchlist, you may want to use a [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) field instead of a ForeignKey

Comment: If you do stay with a fk (which is probably wrong) you're looking for `thing.watchlist = None`.

Comment: Oh ok I see. Since I want to allow multiple users to add a `Thing` to their `WatchList`s, I should use ManyToMany, right? And if I change the field to ManyToMany, how do I remove the `Thing` from a `User`'s `WatchList`? Feel free to answer below and I'll accept it, as this is the true intent of my question. Thanks for everyone's ideas!

Answer (score 8):

First (ok, you already noted it in your edit), you have a Many-to-Many relationship.

You can just set delete the user-entry from the `Thing.watchlist` table. You'll find many examples on how to work with these in [the django documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

In short: You can do `my_thing.watchlist.remove(object_to_be_removed)`.

...and to answer your original question (just in case someone runs into this issue), just set the `ForeignKey` attribute to `None` i.e. `my_thing.watchlist = None`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @OBu. I think I am a lot closer to the answer, as posted in the edit above, but I still cannot remove the WatchList. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Are there any errors? Did you check your database and recognize any changes after executing your code? Are you sure, the code after the if statement is actually executed? (e.g. by setting a breakpoint after the if or by writing a log message)